# TypeError: Could not convert ['2019-03-012019-03-022019-03-032019-03-042019-03 .......] to numeric?

Tags: python, dataframe, integer, concatenation

```
date=pd.DataFrame(data['Date'])


Closing_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data['Close'])


Close1 = Closing_df1.rename(columns={"Close": "data_close"})



close2=pd.concat([date,close1],axis=1) 
close2.head()


data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

data.fillna(data.mean(), inplace=True)  # error here 

data.head()
```

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the `close1` variable different from `Close1`?  The former might be an interger.